TIA Openness 15.1 HMI screens
I am trying to retrieve a list of all screens in the project (and in the future, the tags associated with these screens). The screens are present on the devices shown in the attached screenshot. I've tried running various versions of the code, but I have never managed to get a list of screens. I would greatly appreciate any help.
Here is my code:
import clr
clr.AddReference('C:\\Program Files\\Siemens\\Automation\\Portal V15_1\\PublicAPI\\V15.1\\Siemens.Engineering.dll')
import Siemens.Engineering as tia
import Siemens.Engineering.Hmi as tia_hmi

def connect_to_tia_portal():
   processes = list(tia.TiaPortal.GetProcesses())
   if processes:
      print("Attaching to an existing TIA Portal instance...")
      return processes[0].Attach()
   print("No running TIA Portal instance found. Starting a new instance...")
   return tia.TiaPortal(tia.TiaPortalMode.WithUserInterface)

print('Trying to connect to an open TIA Portal instance...')
try:
   mytia = connect_to_tia_portal()
   print('Connected to an open TIA Portal instance.')
except Exception as e:
   print(f"Failed to connect: {e}")
   quit()

if mytia.Projects.Count == 0:
   print("No open projects found in TIA Portal.")
   quit()

myproject = mytia.Projects[0]
print(f"Connected to project: {myproject.Name}")

screens = []

for device in myproject.Devices:
   print(f"Searching in device: {device.Name}")
   for item in device.DeviceItems:
      if isinstance(item, tia_hmi.HmiTarget): 
         hmi_target = item.GetService(tia_hmi.HmiTagService)
         for screen in hmi_target.HmiScreens:
            screens.append(screen.Name)
            print(f"Screen found: {screen.Name}")

if screens:
   print(f"\nTotal screens found: {len(screens)}")
else:
   print("No screens found in the project.")

print("Press any key to quit")
input()
quit()

Screenshot
Output:
Trying to connect to an open TIA Portal instance...
Attaching to an existing TIA Portal instance...
Connected to an open TIA Portal instance.
Connected to project: uspk_81_04_07_06_V2
Searching in device: ARMKTU
Searching in device: ARMBUR
Searching in device: S71500/ET200MP station_1
No screens found in the project.
Press any key to quit

I have tried different approaches, but the output was approximately as follows:
Searching in device: ARMBUR
Error retrieving HMI Software in SIMATIC PC station: SoftwareContainer
Error retrieving HMI Software in HMI_RT_2: SoftwareContainer
Error retrieving HMI Software in IE general_1: SoftwareContainer


"the devices shown in the attached screenshot" - there is no attached screenshot. What would even be more helpful would be the output you get when running your program. There are a lot of prints in there and they should give you (and readers of your question) some idea what goes wrong.

I added screenshots and outputs
